# How to remove setSelect() when using jCrop

Tags: javascript, jcrop

I'm using jCrop and am trying to clear a previous selection. setSelect is equal to null, however the handles still appear in the top left hand corner. How do I remove these?

I found an old post https://code.google.com/p/jcrop/issues/detail?id=7 on the subject but had no luck with the suggestions.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error this fixed it for me:

```
jCrop = $img.data('Jcrop');
jCrop.release();
```